# Get dataframe cell value based on substring

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to search for a substring across my dataframe (no specific column) and get in return the value of the cell.

For example:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Red apple | carrots |
| Blue Car | Banana |

I’d like to search the cell which contains “Apple” and i should get in return “Red apple”.

i have been successful returning the row which contains the value as following:

```
df[df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains(“Apple”, case=false).any, axis=1)]
```

Or the column name which contains it:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str. contains(“Apple”, case=false).any())
```

But not exactly what i want, the full value of the cell which contains the substring.

Can I please get help?:)

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far. Surely if you can get the index and column, you could feed that into .loc[]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to `stack` and use boolean indexing:

```
s = df.stack()

out = s[s.str.contains('apple')]
```

output:

```
0  Column A    Red apple
dtype: object
```

If you expect a single match:

```
out = s[s.str.contains('apple')].squeeze()
```

output: `'Red apple'`